# laravel:how to get columns name of eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.2 ,i want to get all the column (attribute) name of selected eloquent model,is there way to do this?

following is my code in controller method

```
    if($request->method=="edit")
    {
        /*we are in edit mode details of given news ID should be attached*/
        $curNews=News::find($request->newsID);
        if($curNews==null)return back()->withErrors(["Unable to Edit News:No Data Found For Given News ID"]);

        foreach((array)$curNews->attributes as $key=>$val)
        {
            $data[$key]=$val;
        }

    }

    return view('adminarea.news.news-addedit',$data);
```

Comment: please display some code

Comment: to @aynber ,i just want column name  as array

Comment: @joy it's basics of php, You already have object that has `fieldName = 'some data'`, so it's not laravel question - it's all about basics of php (how to get attributes of object), sorry I'll downvote Your question

Comment: @num8er ,ya you are right but its platform to learn

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users'); // users table
dd($columns); // dump the result and die
```

Comment: Import schema at the top  - use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

Comment: This is how you get column names from table, not model - which was asked in question. If model tables are dynamic and may change - this is not good solution.

Comment: Does not work in 7.x

Comment: for some strange reason, it started auto-sorting keys in alphabetical order. `\array_keys( $model->getAttributes() )` works for me

Comment: For newer Laravel versions (in my case 5.8) just use: `use Schema;` The path with Illuminate\Support\ etc. will not work.

Answer (score 22):

If you want get the names of your attributes, you can try this

```
$item = News::find($request->newsID);

    $attributes = array_keys($item->getOriginal());
// or 
$attributes = array_keys($item->getAttributes());
```

Comment: if it is a collection use $items->first()->getAttributes()

Comment: This is a better way instead of using Schema.

Answer (score 2):

don't know i am right or not, but i have overcome with following code,and its working for me.

```
    if($request->method=="edit")
    {
        /*we are in edit mode details of given news ID should be attached*/
        $curNews=News::find($request->newsID);
        if($curNews==null)return back()->withErrors(["Unable to Edit News:No Data Found For Given News ID"]);

        foreach($curNews->toArray() as $key=>$val)
        {
            $data[$key]=$val;
        }

    }

    return view('adminarea.news.news-addedit',$data);
```