# Show column names of a model in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to Show column names of a model in Laravel Eloquent.
I need a array to use like:

```php
if(in_array($colum, $columns))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818177/laravelhow-to-get-columns-name-of-eloquent-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```php
use Schema;
$accept_columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users');

 if(in_array($orderBy, $accept_columns))
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```